# Comments on 'WinMain' do not match(window api)

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I wrote the code that left-clicks a message box.

But when I tried to run it, it did not run and I got an error message "
The comments for 'WinMain' do not match. This instance has no comments.(korean:'WinMain'에 대한 주석이 일치하지 않습니다. 이 인스턴스에는 주석 없음이(가) 있습니다.)".

I searched hard but could not figure out why. (I also changed the arguments.)

I want to open a message box when I left click.

What should I do?
and I want to know why happen this error

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MouseHookProc(_In_ int    nCode,
    _In_ WPARAM wParam,
    _In_ LPARAM lParam)
{

    switch (wParam) {
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        printf("left");
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(g_Hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance
    , LPSTR lpszCmdParam, int nCmdShow)
{
    HHOOK mouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL,MouseHookProc, hInstance, NULL);

}
```

tries:int APIENTRY WinMain->int WINAPI WinMain

Comment: did LPTSTR solve the problem?

Comment: I tried that but it still didn't run and I got "can't overload winmain function" I tried LPWSTR too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of microsofts annotation habbits the parameter list must be (see WinBase.h):

```
(
    _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int nShowCmd
    )
```

Comment: `_In_` and `_In_opt_` are just empty precompiler macros that don't actually do anything to affect the signature of the function. They are [SAL annotation macros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/sal-annotations?view=vs-2019) for static analysis tools to make use of. A compiler doesn't care about them at all and will ignore them since the preprocessor will remove them during compiling.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: Yes ,but I once had, in either Vs2012 or vs2015, this error/warning (can't repro in vs2017 and vs2019).